# Why the image is not displayed in the imageItem?

Tags: java, image, load, midlet

I used the Nokia sample codes for Google Map. It has retrieveStaticImage method which loads and returns an Image. I them loaded the image to an ImageItem but I get an exception everytime..
Here are my codes...

Codes for GoogleMaps class

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.microedition.io.Connector;
import javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Image;
import javax.microedition.lcdui.ImageItem;

public class GoogleMaps implements Runnable{
    private static final String URL_UNRESERVED =
        "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" +
        "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" +
        "0123456789-_.~";
    private static final char[] HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();
    Image image;
    int width;
    int height;
    double lat;
    double lng;
    int zoom;
    String format;
    ImageItem imagecmpt;
    // these 2 properties will be used with map scrolling methods. You can remove them if not needed
    public static final int offset = 268435456;
    public static final double radius = offset / Math.PI;

    private String apiKey = null;

    public GoogleMaps(String key,int width, int height, double lat, double lng, int zoom,
            String format,ImageItem img) {
        this.width=width;
        this.height=height;
       this.lat=lat;
       this.lng=lng;
       this.zoom=zoom;
this.format=format;
        apiKey = key;

    }

    public double[] geocodeAddress(String address) throws Exception {
        byte[] res = loadHttpFile(getGeocodeUrl(address));
        String[] data = split(new String(res), ',');

        if (!data[0].equals("200")) {
            int errorCode = Integer.parseInt(data[0]);
            throw new Exception("Google Maps Exception: " + getGeocodeError(errorCode));
        }

        return new double[] {
                Double.parseDouble(data[2]), Double.parseDouble(data[3])
        };
    }

    public Image retrieveStaticImage() throws IOException {
        byte[] imageData = loadHttpFile(getMapUrl(width, height, lng, lat, zoom, format));
        System.out.println("Address is "+getMapUrl(width, height, lng, lat, zoom, format));
        for (int i=0;i<imageData.length;i++){
            System.out.println(imageData[i]);
        }
        return Image.createImage(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
    }

    private static String getGeocodeError(int errorCode) {
        switch (errorCode) {
        case 400:
            return "Bad request";
        case 500:
            return "Server error";
        case 601:
            return "Missing query";
        case 602:
            return "Unknown address";
        case 603:
            return "Unavailable address";
        case 604:
            return "Unknown directions";
        case 610:
            return "Bad API key";
        case 620:
            return "Too many queries";
        default:
            return "Generic error";
        }
    }

    private String getGeocodeUrl(String address) {
        return "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=" + urlEncode(address) + "&output=csv&key="
                + apiKey;
    }

    private String getMapUrl(int width, int height, double lng, double lat, int zoom, String format) {
        return "http://maps.google.com/staticmap?center=" + lat + "," + lng + "&format="
                + format + "&zoom=" + zoom + "&size=" + width + "x" + height + "&key=" + apiKey;
    }

    private static String urlEncode(String str) {
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);
            dos.writeUTF(str);
            bytes = bos.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ignore
        }
        for (int i = 2; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            byte b = bytes[i];
            if (URL_UNRESERVED.indexOf(b) >= 0) {
                buf.append((char) b);
            } else {
                buf.append('%').append(HEX[(b >> 4) & 0x0f]).append(HEX[b & 0x0f]);
            }
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

    private static byte[] loadHttpFile(String url) throws IOException {
        byte[] byteBuffer;

        HttpConnection hc = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
        try {
            hc.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.GET);
            InputStream is = hc.openInputStream();
            try {
                int len = (int) hc.getLength();
                if (len > 0) {
                    byteBuffer = new byte[len];
                    int done = 0;
                    while (done < len) {
                        done += is.read(byteBuffer, done, len - done);
                    }
                } else {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
                    int count;
                    while ( (count = is.read(buffer)) >= 0 ) {
                        bos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                    byteBuffer = bos.toByteArray();
                }
            } finally {
                is.close();
            }
        } finally {
            hc.close();
        }

        return byteBuffer;
    }

    private static String[] split(String s, int chr) {
        Vector res = new Vector();

        int curr;
        int prev = 0;

        while ( (curr = s.indexOf(chr, prev)) >= 0 ) {
            res.addElement(s.substring(prev, curr));
            prev = curr + 1;
        }
        res.addElement(s.substring(prev));

        String[] splitted = new String[res.size()];
        res.copyInto(splitted);

        return splitted;
    }

    public void run() {
        try{
        //throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        imagecmpt.setImage(retrieveStaticImage());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error ......."+e);
        }
    }
}
```

code for midlet

```
public void commandAction(Command command, Displayable displayable) {                                               
        // write pre-action user code here
        if (displayable == form) {                                           
            if (command == exitCommand) {                                         
                // write pre-action user code here
                exitMIDlet();                                           
                // write post-action user code here
            } else if (command == okCommand) {                                          
                // write pre-action user code here

                // write post-action user code here

                GoogleMaps cMz=new GoogleMaps("ABQIAAAADEQoVqbqS5pT4ahHSLALyBT8PMUw5z7_OLJoE1lh2VQyfb-WOxTwS9t9mrSq_flhdPeVGOQrxXuCFQ",10, 10, 10, 10, 1, "roadmap", imageItem);

                Thread th=new Thread(cMz);
                th.run();
                Display display=getDisplay ();


            }                                                  
        }                                                
        // write post-action user code here
    }
```

My output:::

```
Starting emulator in execution mode
Running with storage root DefaultColorPhone
Running with locale: English_United States.1252
Running in the identified_third_party security domain
Warning: To avoid potential deadlock, operations that may block, such as 
 networking, should be performed in a different thread than the 
 commandAction() handler.
```

I have used an external thread but yet it keeps telling me to use another thread.. 
How can I sort this out?

Comment: you should accept some of the previous answers also ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
 GoogleMaps cMz=new GoogleMaps("ABQIAAAADEQoVqbqS5pT4ahHSLALyBT8PMUw5z7_OLJoE1lh2VQyfb-WOxTwS9t9mrSq_flhdPeVGOQrxXuCFQ",10, 10, 10, 10, 1, "roadmap", imageItem);


//put here action

}
).start();
```